# cURL "String" vs \"String\" differences

Tags: curl, jsreport

What is the difference between the two?

Usecase that I encountered:
Using curl to send jsreport this 2:

```
curl 
....
-d"{\"template\": { \"shortid\" : \"BJbsfLxl8\" }}" > report.pdf
```

vs

```
curl 
....
-d"{"template": { "shortid" : "BJbsfLxl8" }}" > report.pdf
```

Only case 1 works

Comment: When quotes mark the beginning and end of a string, you need a way to include a quote in the string without it becoming the end. In this case *your shell* uses the `\"` syntax. Note that this has nothing to do with cURL. You can test it with some other command, e.g. `echo`: Observe the difference between `echo "a" b "c"` and `echo "a\" b \"c"`.

Comment: In addition to the comment by @Biffen here some more information regarding [quoting and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)